# Calculating Brier Score from a predictions made with cv.glmnet?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glmnet

I am trying to calculate the Brier Score of a logistic model I made with `cv.glmnet`. After having selected the alpha and lambda values through cross-validation, with a test dataset I applied the `predict()` function, getting the predicted group levels (disease vs. no disease). I thus have two variables, ypredict which is the predicted group status of my test dataset, and ytrue, the true group status of the predicted group.

From this, I am having trouble figuring out how to get the Brier Score from these two response vectors. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using an example dataset:

```
library(glmnet)
library(DescTools)

X_train = as.matrix(MASS::Pima.tr[,1:7])
y_train = ifelse(MASS::Pima.tr[,8] == "Yes",1,0)

fit = cv.glmnet(x=X_train,y=y_train,family="binomial")
```

Let's get the prediction in probabilities:

```
X_test  = as.matrix(MASS::Pima.te[,1:7])
y_test = ifelse(MASS::Pima.te[,8] == "Yes",1,0)
ypredict = predict(fit,X_test,type = "response")

head(ypredict)
  lambda.1se
1  0.5435120
2  0.1603127
3  0.1412934
4  0.1385610
5  0.7309207
6  0.5935130
```

Then using [BrierScore from DescTools](https://rdrr.io/cran/DescTools/man/BrierScore.html) :

```
BrierScore(ypredict,y_test)
[1] 0.3345311
```